# Нужны ли две запятые или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

До конца лета, скидка 30 процентов, на стирку по килограммам.

Answer (score 1):

Запятые не нужны, однако для превращения этой конструкции в предложение нужно либо добавить глагольное сказуемое (*действует* скидка), либо заместить опущенный глагол на тире (до конца лета - скидка на то-то).